# How to call function inside controller inside foreach loop with different parameters value

Tags: php, oop, laravel-4

i am trying to call m custom function repeatedly with same or different parameters value,inside foreach loop parameters depending upon value to key provided my foreach.

```
foreach ($result as $r) {

            if($r->marks1==null || $r->marks2==null)
            {
                echo $r->p_code;
                $toUpdate=$this->getResult($username,$r->p_code);
                print_r($toUpdate);
            }
        }
```

but when i am printing the latest query result i am getting $toUpdate get appended by latest parameter query.

```
Array
(
    [query] => select * from `result` where (`studentid` = ?) and `studentid` = ? and `ccode` = ? and `a_no` = ? order by `date` desc limit 1
    [bindings] => Array
        (
            [0] => XYZ
            [1] => XYZ
            [2] => course123code
            [3] => 12321
        )

    [time] => 0.18
)
```

my user name getting same, while course code is get overrides while finding second result.

i want to get the result `getResult()` inside foreach loop so that it may give the related result for different parameters value.

```
public function getLatestResult($username,$course_code)
{

    $user=new User;
    $currentDetailOfUser=$this->userCurrentDetail($username);

        $userdetail=json_decode($currentDetailOfUser,true);
            $username        =$userdetail['username'];
            $studentid       =$userdetail['userid'];
            $studentBatch    =$userdetail['batch'];
            $programCode     =$userdetail['programCode'];
            $activeSemester  =$userdetail['activesemester'];

        $condition_key=array(
            'studentid' =>$studentid
            );


       $getCurrentResult1 =$user->getDetail('student_result',$condition_key);
       $getCurrentResult2 =$user->getDetail('student_result',$condition_key);
       $resultAssessment1=$getCurrentResult1->where('studentid',$studentid)->where('course_code',$course_code)->where('assignment_no',1)->orderBy('date','Desc')->limit(1)->get();
       $resultAssessment2=$getCurrentResult2->where('studentid',$studentid)->where('course_code',$course_code)->where('assignment_no',2)->orderBy('date','Desc')->limit(1)->get();
       $recentResult=array_merge($resultAssessment1,$resultAssessment2);
        return $recentResult;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad practice if you are fetching data from `db` inside the `foreach loop`.

BTW you can do this by keeping all new result in same array by index its some unique value, it will be look like this-

```
$toUpdate=array();

foreach ($result as $r) {

                if($r->marks1==null || $r->marks2==null)
                {
                    echo $r->p_code;
                    $toUpdate[$r->p_code]=$this->getResult($username,$r->p_code); // added $r->p_code as index to Array - $toUpdate

                }
            }
    print_r($toUpdate); // this will give all the related result according your parameters
```

**[UPDATE]**

Try using `unset($yourarray)` for your next request these array will be new and they assign the new value each time -

```
public function getLatestResult($username,$course_code)
{

    $user=new User;
    $currentDetailOfUser=$this->userCurrentDetail($username);

        $userdetail=json_decode($currentDetailOfUser,true);
            $username        =$userdetail['username'];
            $studentid       =$userdetail['userid'];
            $studentBatch    =$userdetail['batch'];
            $programCode     =$userdetail['programCode'];
            $activeSemester  =$userdetail['activesemester'];

        $condition_key=array(
            'studentid' =>$studentid
            );


       $getCurrentResult1 =$user->getDetail('student_result',$condition_key);
       $getCurrentResult2 =$user->getDetail('student_result',$condition_key);
       $resultAssessment1=$getCurrentResult1->where('studentid',$studentid)->where('course_code',$course_code)->where('assignment_no',1)->orderBy('date','Desc')->limit(1)->get();
       $resultAssessment2=$getCurrentResult2->where('studentid',$studentid)->where('course_code',$course_code)->where('assignment_no',2)->orderBy('date','Desc')->limit(1)->get();


        unset($currentDetailOfUser);
        unset($userdetail);
        unset($condition_key);
        unset($recentResult);

        $recentResult=array_merge($resultAssessment1,$resultAssessment2);
        return $recentResult;

}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Ya you are right that its a bad practice but even though , i need it , just see the mysql query that i have posted in my question Student_id getting appended while the p_code gets overwrited , is it because i am  looking for diff p_code for same user?

Comment: can u post your `getResult` code as well? so it will be good to check everything before go for any other solution.

Comment: @user3345331 - Can u please tell what is the difference between these:
`$getCurrentResult1=$user->getDetail('student_result',$condition_key);

$getCurrentResult2=$user->getDetail('student_result',$condition_key);`. Same `$condition_key'` and `$studentid`. I why are you getting two times same result and you have merged them as well why? That could be the issue.

Comment: by doing so i am trying to get data stored in two rows of a table and return the same in one single array

Comment: You can get all the rows with single request from DB if one condition matches in multiple rows. Did you try to print `$getCurrentResult1'. i'm sure it will give both rows within single request. Or i went off the road.

Comment: ya i tried but i am looking for 2 separate latest result whose assessment id =1 and assessment id =2 limit 1.
Hope u may get what i am looking for.

Comment: Ok. did you try to print `$recentResult`. if your conditions are true for both assessment then `$recentResult` will give you two records.

Comment: YEs my $recentResult Gives me the 2 result as i want but not every time , when i call it inside foreach loop it appends the query clause Refer the question

Comment: not exactly but i have cleared max of my result by this answer, i as unsetting my variable at wrong place previously .Thankx